# How to configure filter settings for jp@gc - Synthesis Report in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jmeter-plugins, synthesis, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have imported the  "jp@gc - Synthesis Report" plugin in a project jmeter built with maven , but I would set parameters to filter the summary report.

For example I would filter only the rows of report starting with "YJ" and excluding those ending with "-0".

I'm able to do it from GUI, but I would generate the report specifying those parameters in pom.xml, if it has sense.

How can I configure the pom.xml in order to generate a "Synthesis Report" and specifying filtering parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jmeter-graph-tool-maven-plugin](https://github.com/vdaburon/jmeter-graph-tool-maven-plugin#jmeter-graph-tool-maven-plugin), it provides the functionality which is similar to [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd) but from the Maven [POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

Something like:

```
<graph>
    <pluginType>SynthesisReport</pluginType>
    <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/result.jtl</inputFile>
    <generateCsv>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/synthesis.csv</generateCsv>
    <includeLabels>YJ.*</includeLabels>
    <includeLabelRegex>true</includeLabelRegex>
    <excludeLabels>.*-0</excludeLabels>
    <excludeLabelRegex>true</excludeLabelRegex>
</graph>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri , this is a good input